# How to make lines between elements adaptive?

Tags: html, css, sass

The problem is that I have template with this lines between divs and I don't understand how to make them adaptive. Making the media request everytime isn't good idea)

[image]

My code is like:

```
<div class="completed__snake">
        <div class="completed__snake-item">
          <p class="completed__snake-number">980
            </p>
          <p class="completed__snake-name">Project</p>
        </div>
</div>

    &__snake {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

&__snake-item {
    height: 185px;
    width: 185px;
    
    
    border-radius: 40px 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;


    &:not(:last-child)::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 40px;
        height: 50%;
        right: -50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        border-top: 2px solid violet;
        border-right: 2px solid violet;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.ex-container {
    resize: both;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.flex {
    min-width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.lines-between, .lines-between * {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.lines-between {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    min-width: 50px;
    display: flex;
}


.item {
    height: 100px;
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex .item:nth-child(4n+3) {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.flex .lines-between:nth-child(2n+2) {
    align-self: center;
}

.flex .lines-between:nth-child(4n+2)  *:nth-child(2n+1) {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.flex .lines-between:nth-child(4n+2)  *:nth-child(1n+2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.flex .lines-between:nth-child(4n)  *:nth-child(2n+1) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.flex .lines-between:nth-child(4n)  *:nth-child(1n+2) {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="ex-container">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="item">1</div>
            <div class="lines-between">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">2</div>
            <div class="lines-between">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">3</div>
            <div class="lines-between">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```